# Bootstrap 4 - select border larger then 1 px

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am migrating a Bootstrap 3 codebase to Bootstrap 4.

I our custom css we apply a custom border-width to `.form-control`

For demonstration purposes lets say 4px.

```
.form-control {
    border-width: 4px;
}
```

This results in different "heights" of `input` and `select` fields.

See this Codepen (tested with latest Firefox):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZRprmG

How can I properly style `select` form controls to have the same border and height like `input` fields? **Edit: Bonus** Why is there this difference?

Comment: your select has a `height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);` defined. If you put this on the input aswell it will have the same height.

Comment: or just define the class: "select.form-control" and height to be "44px"

Comment: @Maharkus  I have competely overseen that. I updated my question. Sorry for the mess. If you formulate this as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: @madflow glad I could help :). I think you should make your own answer (and mark it as accepted) though, as my comment only helped you get to the correct solution and you worked it out by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not mention that we are using the SASS Bootstrap Build. @Maharkus comment brought me on the right track: The SASS build "calculates" the height by using $input-border-width. By setting this to 2px it works properly.

```
// custom.scss
$input-border-width: 2px !default;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your **CSS**:

```
#inputState {

  height: 2.75em;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#inputState{
    height: 44px;
}
```

**As declare to input:**
[image]

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 0):

```
input.form-control, select.form-control {
   min-height: 46px ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your style --

```
#inputState{
height: 44px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
.form-control {
   min-height:58%;
 }
```

working link : https://codepen.io/sidhanshu28/pen/VdKXxq